# Writing to txt file using variables

Tags: angular

In my Angular program, I want to be able to click on a button which then opens a window displaying a report or summary of that month and have successfully done so, but I can't include variables for some reason. Whenever I have `Report for date {{monthlyEndDate}}` in my html text, it prints out exactly that without using the binding. How can I accomplish this?

Here's my .ts file and my button just calls the `printMonthlyReport()` function:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-report',
    templateUrl: `./report.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})

export class ReportComponent {

    date = new Date();
    monthlyStartDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1);
    monthlyEndDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    
    printMonthlyReport(): void {
        let popupWin;
        popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write(`
          <html>
            <head>
              <title>Monthly PTO/ETO Report</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <h3>Monthly PTO/ETO Payroll Report {{monthlyEndDate}}</h3>
            </body>
          </html>
`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I ask why do you need to open a new window?

Comment: Looks like you have a text template. I'm not super familiar with using tilds in templates but have you tried including your variable like so: ` + monthlyEndDate + `?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov because I want to be able to print the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
`bla bla ${this.fieldName} bla bla`
```

So, access the field variable using `this`, and wrap your variable around `${}` within a template string (``)

```
popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Monthly PTO/ETO Report</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h3>Monthly PTO/ETO Payroll Report ${this.monthlyEndDate}</h3>
        </body>
      </html>
`)
```

Comment: no, you cannot use directives inside a string. Only within an `@Component.template`

Comment: ah, darn. Is there any way to include a template inside the `popupWin.document.write`?

Comment: I don't know the best way. A hacky way around it.. you could have a `display:hidden` element in your `ReportComponent` template which contains what you want to display in your popup. Then create an `ElementRef` to that element, and use `nativeElement.innerHTML` to access the content and pass this to `popupWin.document.write`

Comment: oh, okay. Thanks!